# Major differences between scala.util.Success and akka.actor.Status.Success?

Tags: scala, akka

I was wondering what is a comprehensive list of major differences between scala.util.Success and akka.actor.Status.Success?

And in what cases are they interchangable, if at all?

Comment: Same differences as Bill Gates (Microsoft) and some other totally unrelated guy name Bill Gates who also works in software industry. They are not interchangable in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`akka.actor.Status.Success` is a wrapper which can be used as a message to quickly indicate to another actor that some operation completed successfully.  Accordingly it provides no API beyond extraction.

`scala.util.Success[T]` is one of the two subtypes of `scala.util.Try`, which is a monadic(-ish, it doesn't fully obey the monad laws, for a good reason) representation of an operation that can fail (in this case, `Success` contains the result of a successful operation).  It's fairly rare, in practice, to directly create `scala.util.Success`s: you most often will create a `Try`.

While they both encode some notion of "an operation was successfully attempted", `scala.util.Success` pertains more to the operation itself and `akka.actor.Status.Success` pertains more to the notification of success.  In fact, it might well make sense, within the actor performing some operation which can fail, to have code like

```
import akka.actor.Status
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }

def attemptAndReport(reportTo: ActorRef)(operation: => Unit): Unit =
  Try(operation) match {
    case _: Success =>
      // since it's a Unit-returning operation, there's only one value that could be wrapped by Success: ()
      reportTo ! Status.Success("operation succeeded")
    case Failure(e) =>
      reportTo ! Status.Failure(e)
  }
```

That code is a little contorted to shoehorn both `Success`es.  It would be more natural and useful to have something like

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

 def attemptAndReport[Result](reportTo: ActorRef, successMsg: Result => Any)(operation: => Result): Unit = {
   val reportMsg = Try(operation)           // Try[Result]
     .map(r => Status.Success(successMsg))  // Try[Status.Success]... icky, but this is Akka Classic...
     .recover {
       case NonFatal(e) => Status.Failure(e)
     }                                      // Try[Status]
   reportMsg.foreach(reportTo ! _)
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much for taking time and provide such a great answer.